# OWASP ZAP Tool is not tracing in IE8

Tags: sql-injection, owasp

Currently I'm working on penetration testing particularly SQL Injection, for that I'm using OWASP ZAP tool, after configuration I can able to trace my web application into that ZAP tool, but the thing is I can't able to trace my web application that I'm running in my IE8. Actually in manual clearly they mentioned it will support for IE8, but I can't. Please provide me some suggestions regarding this.

Thanks in advance.
Kesavakumar V

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ZAP will support IE8 - I've tested it myself.

I'm assuming that you have configured ZAP as IE8's proxy as per: http://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/wiki/HelpStartProxies

Is you target app on the same machine? IE can be a pain when talking to local apps and will often ignore the proxy settings.
If so make sure 'Bypass proxy server for local addresses' is *unchecked*.

Whether you are targetting a local app or not make sure that the target host name is *not* in the IE8 Proxy Settings 'Exceptions' list - in IE8 / Internet Options / 'Local Area Network (LAN) Settings' dialog click on the 'Advanced' button.

If the target host is in the Exceptions list then remove it.

Hopefully that will do the trick.

This is likely to be an 'IE' issue rather than a ZAP one. If you configure IE to use ZAP and nothing appears in ZAP then close ZAP and keep trying to use IE. If it carries on working then it is ignoring the proxy settings :)

Let me know if this works or not.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead).

PS we also have a [user group](http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users), which you may well get faster answers on ;)